# Google sheets validation dropdown changes option order — can I stop this?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-data-validation

I am trying to speed up data entry using a validation range sorted with most-recent values first. When I click the dropdown triangle, the values appear in a different order from the validation range. That defeats the purpose of putting newest values at the top.

If anyone can tell me how to stop this unwanted reordering, I'll be super grateful.

Answer (score 1):

My goof! The dropdown was only reordering when some data was entered — actually helpfully putting values similar to the incomplete entry at the top of the list. (I couldn't find a way to delete the question, or I would have.)